# How Do I Do this Simple Conditional Update?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL 2000 server with a database (ITinventory) and a table which is also called ITinventory.  I would like to create a query which will look at the field 'Status', if the status is 'disposed' then I would like to set a 'location' field to 'disposed'.

Comment: What is the table structure? What have you tried? What isn't working? Can you post your SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE ITinventory
SET location = 'disposed'
WHERE status = 'disposed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ITInventory SET Location = 'disposed' 
WHERE Status = 'disposed' AND Location != 'disposed'
```

Comment: This could save considerable time if most of the records have already been set to disposed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
update 
    ITinventory 
set 
    Location = Status 
where 
    Status = 'Disposed'
```

Comment: Over engineered, without any need to do so. Who told you Location and Status are related at all ?

Comment: I disagree, the poster has indicated he's setting the Location column value to the same as the Status column, where the Status column has a specific value. This query reduces the amount of free text in the query, while forcing the person running it to recognise the logic that it's performing - potentially making you think about how valid the update is a little better. That said, it's just a quick update statement, I doubt it really matters!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ITInventory SET Location = 'disposed' WHERE Status = 'disposed'
```

This SQL is making various assumptions otherwise not clarified in the OP...

Answer (score 0):

```
update ITinventory
set location='disposed'
where status ='disposed'
```